# Collect Signatures workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a Collect Signatures workflow in SP Designer 2010 that assign tasks to workers on a list.

The built in logic is that if the workers don't complete their tasks on time they will get an Email reminder ahead of the end date of the task.

My problem is that the workflow is sending reminders to all the workers in the list even those who had finished their tasks that were assigned to them.

Any thoughts and ideas what can by the issue?

Comment: Without seeing the workflow logic, it is hard to see what may be going wrong. It would be helpful to see the conditions around sending emails to users, and how you are checking to see whether tasks are complete or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would use logic on a workflow that checks to see if that specific task and that worker has finished the task, if they have completed the task then don't send email. If they haven't completed the task then send email. HTH